# What is the probability that Johan, who is one of the applicants, will get a type $B$ scholarship?

Tags: probability

Suppose that University of the Witwatersrand this year received a total of $18$ scholarship applications from PhD registered students. There are $15$ scholarships available:
$5$ type $A$ scholarships, $7$ type $B$ scholarships and $3$ type $C$ scholarships. The rules
are that all the scholarships must be awarded and each of the applicants may get at
most one of the scholarships.

What is the probability that Johan, who is one of the applicants, will get a type B scholarship?

(State any assumptions you made in arriving at your answer.)

I just want to see different approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a comment, but reputation lacks so I do it with an answer (that will be deleted after some time).

**What is your question?**

**edit**:

Place your comment on this 'answer' in your question.

**edit2** (real answer)

If I understand well then $7$ scholarships $B$ are divided over $18$ persons. Johan is one of the $18$ persons and has probability $\frac{7}{18}$ to get a scholarship $B$.

Comment: What is the probability that Johan, who is one of the applicants, will get a type B scholarship?

Comment: it's in the title?

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice that. Personally I think that a question formulated like that does not belong there. That's the reason why it didn't spot it.

Answer (score 0):

### We may reformulate the problem...

You have 18 applications and 18 scholarships:

- $5$ Type $A$ scholarships
- $7$ Type $B$ scholarships
- $3$ Type $C$ scholarships
- $3$ Type $N$ scholarships
  where the $N$ scholarships are in reallity No-scholarship scholarships.

Now it's quite obvious that the probability of a random selection results B is
$$ \frac{7}{18} $$

### A standard approach

Probability of John being selected for a scholarship:
$$ P_{selection} = \frac{|Scholarships|}{|Applicants|} = \frac{15}{18} $$

Being selected, probability that the scholarship is of type B:
$$ P_B = \frac{|Bscholarships|}{|Scholarships|} = \frac{7}{15} $$

Therefore the probability of being selected with scholarship B is
$$ P_{selection}P_B = \frac{7}{18} $$